# add more than one edge based on edge attributes using igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to know wether, using `igraph`, it is possible to add edges to a graph depending on the values of different edge attributes.

I have a data.frame, which `dput` is the following:

```
df <- structure(list(nodeA = c("CFTR", "CFTR", "CFTR", "CFTR", "CFTR", 
"CFTR"), nodeB = c("CYP7A1", "KRT16", "ABCA3", "SLC22A11", 
"PBK", "ACSM1"), score = c(0.239, 0.24, 0.292, 0.269, 
0.233, 0.168), text = c(129L, 0L, 287L, 246L, 
161L, 155L), mining = c(163L, 241L, 413L, 71L, 92L, 56L), 
experiments = c(0L, 0L, 101L, 0L, 75L, 0L), homologs =c(0L, 
0L, 609L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("nodeA", "nodeB", 
"score", "text", "mining","experiments", 
"homologs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

I would like to add new edges to the graph (`g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=FALSE`) if the value of the edge attributes is different from 0, for example for the edge `CFTR--CYP7A1`, I would like to add a pair of extra edges (one for the `text` and another for the `mining` attributes), I am not interested in `score` (it is the weight of my the graph)

Comment: `m <- reshape2::melt(df, id.=1:2) ;
m <- m[m$value!=0, ] ; g <- graph.data.frame(m, directed=FALSE)` . Is this the expected outcome?

Comment: close but not @user20650, I want to add edges to the whole graph. I mean, I want to plot my complete graph (27 nodes and 91 edges), but in addition to these 91 edges I want to draw additional ones between nodes where the edge.attributes are different from 0

Comment: of course. I expected to add edges to the original graph, say in another colour depending on the attribute, but for the data in your question, are all the expected edges there? Just making sure of the expected outcome.

Comment: yep, those are the expected edges to be added @user20650

Comment: @user20650, did you have a change to add the code for adding the edges you calculated to the graph, and change his colour depending on the attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways.

First, rearranging your original data seems a bit easier. Put the data in to long format and assign colours based on the column names.

```
library(reshape2)
# Data in long format 
# Create graph, with edges add when attributes / columns are greater than zero
m <- melt(df, id=1:2)
m <- m[m$value != 0, ] # keep non-zero values
g <- graph.data.frame(m, directed=FALSE)

# Add colours to the edges
cols = c(score="black", text="blue", mining="green", 
                                  experiments="red", homologs="yellow")
plot(g, edge.color=cols[E(g)$variable])
```

---

If you want to have the original graph and then add coloured edges for each 
attribute greater than zero, you can loop through the attributes
(`edge_attr`), and add edges (`add_edges`) when the condition is met.

We can add the additional edges one at a time (shown for the `text` attribute)

```
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=FALSE)    
names(edge_attr(g)) # attributes

# Which edges should be added conditioned on text attribute being greater than zero
edge_attr(g, "text")
ats <- edge_attr(g, "text") > 0

#Set edges in graph already to black
E(g)$color <- "black"

# Get head and tail of all edges
ed <- get.edgelist(g)

# subset these by the attribute condition
# combine head and tail nodes in correct format for add_edges
# should be c(tail1, head1, tail2, head2, ..., tailn, headn)
ed <- t(ed[ats, 2:1])

# Add the additional edges
g  <- add_edges(g, ed,  color="blue")
plot(g)
```

Or add the additional edges in one go

```
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=FALSE)    

# Indicator of attribute > 0
ats <- unlist(edge_attr(g)) > 0

# Repeat the head & tail of each edge
# subset so the same length as relevant attributes
ed <- do.call(rbind, replicate(length(edge_attr(g)), get.edgelist(g), simplify=FALSE))
ed <- t(ed[ats, 2:1])
cols <- rep(c("black", "blue", "green", "red", "yellow"), each=length(E(g)))[ats]

g  <- add_edges(g, ed,  color=cols)
plot(g)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this gets you what you want with a bit of melting and casting:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

#get list of potential edges
tmp <- melt(df, id.vars = c("nodeA","nodeB","score"), measure.vars = c("text","mining","experiments","homologs"))

#Filter out zeros, create unique group for each edge
tmp <- tmp[value != 0, ][, ind := .I]

#Recast
tmp <- dcast(tmp, ind + nodeA + nodeB + score ~ variable, value.var = "value", fill = 0)

#get rid of index
tmp[, ind := NULL]

#join back to initial edge list
df <- rbindlist(list(df, tmp))
df
    nodeA    nodeB score text mining experiments homologs
 1:  CFTR   CYP7A1 0.239  129    163           0        0
 2:  CFTR    KRT16 0.240    0    241           0        0
 3:  CFTR    ABCA3 0.292  287    413         101      609
 4:  CFTR SLC22A11 0.269  246     71           0        0
 5:  CFTR      PBK 0.233  161     92          75        0
 6:  CFTR    ACSM1 0.168  155     56           0        0
 7:  CFTR   CYP7A1 0.239  129      0           0        0
 8:  CFTR    ABCA3 0.292  287      0           0        0
 9:  CFTR SLC22A11 0.269  246      0           0        0
10:  CFTR      PBK 0.233  161      0           0        0
11:  CFTR    ACSM1 0.168  155      0           0        0
12:  CFTR   CYP7A1 0.239    0    163           0        0
13:  CFTR    KRT16 0.240    0    241           0        0
14:  CFTR    ABCA3 0.292    0    413           0        0
15:  CFTR SLC22A11 0.269    0     71           0        0
16:  CFTR      PBK 0.233    0     92           0        0
17:  CFTR    ACSM1 0.168    0     56           0        0
18:  CFTR    ABCA3 0.292    0      0         101        0
19:  CFTR      PBK 0.233    0      0          75        0
20:  CFTR    ABCA3 0.292    0      0           0      609
```