# adding edges to nodes in a graph faster with igraph in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, igraph

I am trying to add edges to a graph with a for loop. The for loop adds edges to a graph based on the nodes in *x* and *y*. *x* is a vector of nodes that several nodes in *y* need to form an edge to.

I have create a nested for loop to loop through the indices of the list, and the number of nodes in each index of *y*, but it is slow. I would like to speed this up as the graph can get much larger than just 6 nodes (~thousands). I tried using the apply function (open to other faster suggestions if available) for this to make it faster, but have been unsuccessful.

```
library(igraph)

x = 1:6

head(y)
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 6

[[3]]
[1] 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 5 3

[[5]]
[1] 4 6 5 3

g = graph.empty(6, directed = FALSE)

g
IGRAPH U--- 6 0 -- 
+ edges:
```

What I have is this

```
for (m in 1:length(y)) {    
    for (j in 1:length(y[[m]])) {
        g = add.edges(g, edges = c(x[m], y[[m]][j]))
    }
}

g 
IGRAPH U--- 6 11 -- 
+ edges:
 [1] 1--3 2--2 2--6 3--3 3--4 4--5 3--4 4--5 5--6
[10] 5--5 3--5
```

**EDIT** 
Trying to troubleshoot the error I get using the suggested code looks like this:

```
set.seed(1)
x=1:5
x = as.numeric(x)
y = vector(mode='list', length=5)
y[[1]] = 3
y[[2]] = c(2,6)
y[[3]] = c(3,4)
y[[4]] = c(5,3)
y[[5]] = c(4,6,5,3)
class(x); class(y)
#[1] "numeric"
#[1] "list"
sum(is.na(x)) != 0
#[1] FALSE
length(x) == length(y)
#[1] TRUE
edges = stack(setNames(y, x[1:length(y)]))
#Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"numeric"’

edges = na.omit(as.data.frame(lapply(stack(setNames(y, x[1:length(y)])), function(col) as.numeric(as.character(col)))))
#Error in as.data.frame(lapply(stack(setNames(y, x[1:length(y)])), function(col) as.numeric(as.character(col)))) : 
  #error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  #unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

Comment: you can pass multiple edges to add_edges , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800516/add-more-than-one-edge-based-on-edge-attributes-using-igraph/39862276#39862276

Comment: You may want to restart your R session. I am not getting the error message for both versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the list y and node x to an edge data frame, and then call `graph.data.frame` directly to construct the graph at once, this avoids using for loop and add edges one by one which should be faster (untested):

```
library(igraph)
edges = na.omit(stack(setNames(y, x[1:length(y)])))
graph.data.frame(edges, directed = FALSE)

IGRAPH UN-- 6 11 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):
 [1] 3--1 2--2 2--6 3--3 3--4 4--5 3--4 4--5 6--5 5--5 3--5
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of graph.data.frame. I'm getting a warning with your approach regarding NAs being made in graph.data.frame. How did you deal with these?

_Warning messages:
1: In graph.data.frame(edges, directed = FALSE) :
  In `d' `NA' elements were replaced with string "NA"
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "NA") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated_

Comment: Hmm. It seems like your vector x is shorter than y. Maybe you need to check on that firstly. Ideally, if I understand correctly, x should have the same length as y, is that correct?

Comment: I tried with an x of the same length as y and got the same warning. Are you unlisting y by any chance? If I unlist y I get the warning I mentioned: 

`edges=stack(setNames(unlist(y), x[1:length(unlist(y))]))`

If I do not unlist y I get this error _Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"numeric"’_

Comment: No, don't unlist y. The `raster` seems strange to me. If you check `class(x)`, `class(y)` do you get `numeric` and `list` as the results?

Comment: yeah, `class(x)` is `numeric` and `class(y)` is `list`

Comment: A few things I would check then. `length(x) == length(y)`? `sum(is.na(x)) != 0`? And finally maybe `edges = na.omit(as.data.frame(lapply(stack(setNames(y, x[1:length(y)])), function(col) as.numeric(as.character(col)))))`, this is a little bit brute force but should at least get you a working example. You may have missing values in y.

Comment: `length(x)==length(y)` is `TRUE` `sum(is.na(x)) != 0` is `FALSE` maybe an edit to the original post with some example inputs will help?

Comment: Surely, if you can update a reproducible example which fails with the above code, it would be helpful.